# How to optimize this Selenium WebDriver code (Linq?)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and C#.

I know this code is not optimal, can you advise how I can write such things quicker and shorter?

Basically I am searching for a button, href of which contains "addNewProduct".

```
        var addButtons = _driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Add"));
        IWebElement addNewProductButton = null;

        foreach (IWebElement button in addButtons) {
            if (button.GetAttribute("href").Contains("addNewProduct")){
                addNewProductButton = button;
                break;
            }
        }

        addNewProductButton.Click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of XPath or CSS Selector.

**XPath**

```
IWebElement btnAdd = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'addNewProduct')]"));
```

**CSS Selector**

```
IWebElement btnAdd = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*='addNewProduct']"));
```

I recommend CSS Selector since they are faster and the syntax is more concise.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please advise where I can learn how to create those CCS Selector and Xpath statements?

Comment: The first results from googling "XPath Tutorial" and "CSS Selector Tutorial" are pretty good. Then use something like Firebug (with FireFinder for XPath) to test your queries before using them in Selenium